# adding text above icon in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there any way how I can show a little description above specific icon in Jetpack Compose like in this picture?

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to always be visible or only when user clicks on the icon or something?

Comment: Only when user pressing icon, but mainly I dont know how to create that composable... I was thinking about stack, but i dont really know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called speech or tooltip bubble. You can create this or any shape using GenericShape or adding RoundedRect.

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(10.dp)
) {

    var showToolTip by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))

    val triangleShape = remember {
        GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            lineTo(width / 2, height)
            lineTo(width, 0f)
            lineTo(0f, 0f)
        }
    }

    Box {

        if (showToolTip) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.offset(y = (-48).dp)) {


                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                        .shadow(2.dp)
                        .background(Color(0xff26A69A))
                        .padding(8.dp),
                ) {
                    Text("Hello World", color = Color.White)
                }


                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .offset(x = 15.dp)
                        .clip(triangleShape)
                        .width(20.dp)
                        .height(16.dp)
                        .background(Color(0xff26A69A))
                )
            }
        }

        IconButton(
            onClick = { showToolTip = true }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = "null",
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.Red, CircleShape)
                    .padding(4.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

If you need shadow or border that must be a single shape you need to build it with `GenericShape`. You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70938029/5457853) out and [library i built](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Speech-Bubble).

The sample below is simplified version of library, with no Modifier.layout which is essential for setting space reserved for arrow and setting padding correctly instead of creating another Box with Padding

Result

[image]

```
fun getBubbleShape(
    density: Density,
    cornerRadius: Dp,
    arrowWidth: Dp,
    arrowHeight: Dp,
    arrowOffset: Dp
): GenericShape {

    val cornerRadiusPx: Float
    val arrowWidthPx: Float
    val arrowHeightPx: Float
    val arrowOffsetPx: Float

    with(density) {
        cornerRadiusPx = cornerRadius.toPx()
        arrowWidthPx = arrowWidth.toPx()
        arrowHeightPx = arrowHeight.toPx()
        arrowOffsetPx = arrowOffset.toPx()
    }

    return GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->

        val rectBottom = size.height - arrowHeightPx
        this.addRoundRect(
            RoundRect(
                rect = Rect(
                    offset = Offset.Zero,
                    size = Size(size.width, rectBottom)
                ),
                cornerRadius = CornerRadius(cornerRadiusPx, cornerRadiusPx)
            )
        )
        moveTo(arrowOffsetPx, rectBottom)
        lineTo(arrowOffsetPx + arrowWidthPx / 2, size.height)
        lineTo(arrowOffsetPx + arrowWidthPx, rectBottom)

    }
}
```

Then create a Bubble Composable, i set static values but you can set these as parameters

```
@Composable
private fun Bubble(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val arrowHeight = 16.dp

    val bubbleShape = remember {
        getBubbleShape(
            density = density,
            cornerRadius = 12.dp,
            arrowWidth = 20.dp,
            arrowHeight = arrowHeight,
            arrowOffset = 30.dp
        )
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(bubbleShape)
            .shadow(2.dp)
            .background(Color(0xff26A69A))
            .padding(bottom = arrowHeight),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it as in this sample. You need to change offset of Bubble to match position of ImageButton

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(10.dp)
) {

    var showToolTip by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))

    Box {

        if (showToolTip) {
            Bubble(
                modifier = Modifier.offset(x = (-15).dp, (-52).dp),
                text = "Hello World"
            )
        }

        IconButton(
            onClick = { showToolTip = true }
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = "null",
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.Red, CircleShape)
                    .padding(4.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Box. The children of the Box layout will be stacked over each other.

```
Box{ 
    Text(text = "Text Above Icon", modifier = text alignment)
    Icon(... , modifier = icon alignment) 
    
}
```